# Find out what web server a Rails app is working on on the hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx

I'm given access to a Rails application which is hosted on a Linux machine. I need to setup a redirection from `www` to the root domain and, although it can be done via the application using `before_filter` or `route.rb`, it's better to do it via the web server. But I don't know what web server it's working on. It may or may not be nginx - I don't know. This is what I need to find out. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Launch your browser.
- Open the developer tools, go to the `Network` tab
- Navigate to the web app.
- On the left panel, click on any of the loaded resources.
- Select the `Headers` tab and find the `Server` header within the `Response headers` section.

This screenshot was made with Chrome (it's slightly different with Firefox or IE)

[image: An example with Chrome]

Comment: but it's not a reliable way, the server may not send that header.

Comment: True. The only reliable way to find out would be to have access to the machine in question and list the processes running.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following in command line:

curl -I www.yoururl.com

or

curl -I youripaddress

When I run this for my server I see:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 27 Dec 2014 02:20:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
```

This is a super quick way to find out!  :)
Good luck!!